# Is there a way to see a one-line description of what a package does?

Tags: homebrew

If I do a 'brew search', lists a bunch of packages meeting the search

```
$ brew search json
json-c        json-glib     json_spirit   jsonpp    pdf2json      qjson
```

but is there a way to get a one line description of what each package does?  If I do a 'brew info', it might have a link to a homepage for that package, but I want a quick one-liner (like apt)

Answer (score 1):

You can search on this website http://searchbrew.com

Comment: Ok, not bad.  Would prefer something just on the command-line, but this is the next best thing.  My use case is "Ok, I'm got some messy JSON or something, and I want to pretty-print.  What does homebrew offer to do that."

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew by design does not maintain package descriptions.  So the short answer is no.

Of course you could try to write a script that looks at the packages' home pages (`brew home ...`) or looks up the entries on some encyclopedia of open-source software, but that would be up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`brew search --desc json`

To get a one-line description of every package.